# Efficient algorithm for pairwise nearest neighbor search

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, nearest-neighbor

Suppose that I have a dataset in `R^(n * d)` of `n` data points each with `d` dimensions.  I would like to compute the `k` nearest neighbors of each of these `n` points amongst themselves, resulting in an `N^(n*k)` matrix of indices of the `k` nearest neighbors of each of the `n` points.  **NOTE THAT** *this is distinct for ordinary nearest neighbor search* since we need not compute the nearest neighbors for *arbitrary* points, but only pairwise amongst the original `n` training data.

I can think of a couple of naive implementations.

First, performing a [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Linear_search) at each point requires `~ O(n)` per point, which, over the entire dataset becomes `~ O(n^2)`, which is quite slow.  This is more or less equivalent to simply constructing the pairwise distance matrix is also `~ O(n^2)`, obviously.

Second, we could build a [ball tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree) which requires `~ O(n log n)` to build, and `~ O(log n)` per point to compute the nearest neighbors.  Performing `n` such computations requires itself `~ O(n log n)`, and so the whole process is `~ O(n log n)`.  However, the point of the ball tree is to perform nearest neighbor search for *arbitrary* inputs, and so seems to be "too strong" when we only want the nearest neighbors of the original training points.

Is it possible to, e.g. perform the linear search above for all of the points simultaneously, making an `O(n)` algorithm for the entire problem?  Or is `~ O(n log n)` the best we can do here.

Comment: Just finding the nearest neighbor pair among N points in 1D takes time O(N Log N). A linear time solution is out of question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust nm.  [nearest neighbor graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_graph#One-dimensional_case)

Comment: How big is d? The [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) is in effect.